# "Answer your own question" = accepted answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer

If I use the "answer your own question" option, will my answer be marked as accepted?

If not, that seems rather useless...

Comment: « that seems rather useless» From which point of view? Could you clarify this a bit? :)

Comment: @The feature would be useless if you could answer your own question, but you cannot mark your answer as the accepted one. The question would be correctly answered, but not marked as such.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I thought you meant (with the equal sign in your title) that answering your own question *must* bring to automatically accepting it, otherwise it would be useless. It seems I didn't get the meaning right then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *can* mark it as the accepted answer.

It's not automatic though. There are scenarios where you might have multiple options to accomplish the same thing. You might prefer somebody else's answer (and mark that as accepted) but still want your answer available to other people.

In terms of reputation, you don't get the +2 for marking an answer to your question accepted, or the +15 for getting an accepted answer.

Comment: Wait, do you get +2 for accepting your own answer? I thought you gained *no* rep at all for accepting your own answer. Not the +15, not the +2: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: I'm with you, I didn't think you got any for it. Answer was edited. Have they changed something @Seth ?

Comment: @muru they must have changed it somewhere down the line.. every question of mine that I have answered has given me 2 reputation for accepting it.

Comment: I just accepted [my own answer on this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/703070/does-ubuntu-work-on-a-raspberry-pi-zero). No +2 :(

Comment: @Seth I did a check on the data from http://askubuntu.com/reputation `1 .* (2)` is the +2 for accepts. I have 18 questions with an accepted answer, of which 6 are self-accepts. Correspondingly only 12 lines match `1 .*(2)`. So, it didn't work in 2009, and it hasn't worked since 2014-15, when I became active.

Comment: @muru hmm, weird. I could swear I've gotten it several times, but I haven't self answered in a while. I'll revert the edit.